# DateTime ToString() not printing in specified format

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to print the date in the following format: 01/14/2024. To achieve I have written the following code

```
@DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

However, the output looks like this: 01-14-2024.

I'm a little lost as to why it is converting / to -

Running .Net Core 7 web application on windows 11 machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a datetime format, a slash has a special meaning: it's a separator. It gets turned into something else depending on your culture.

Here's an example:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-CA")));
```

At the time of writing, the above will print

```
01/14/2024
01/14/2024
01-14-2024
```

As you see, Canadian cultures use dashes. American cultures get slashes, as does the invariant culture.

If you don't specify a culture (as you do in your question), the *current* culture will be used, and that depends on your machine's configuration.

You could use the invariant culture if that's good enough for you.

Alternatively, you can escape the slashes with backslashes:

```
now.ToString("MM\\/dd\\/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on your current culture. What is the output of `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToString()` ?

For example, the following works.

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

But for Turkey, it prints as follows.

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR")).Dump();
//01.14.2024
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the slashes like this:

```
@DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM'/'dd'/'yyyy")
```

Output:

```
01/14/2024
```

Be aware: This will print the slash regardless of the current culture. Use this when you want to force a specific output no matter on which machine your code is running.
If you rather want to be culture-aware, the other answers here will help.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to replace all the "-" with "/", this can be achieved by using this line but replacing "string" with the name of the variable containing "01-14-24":

```
string.Replace("-", "/");
```

This will go through your entire string and replace every - with a /.